# call parent window function in child window javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, window

Hi I want to run function from parent window in child window

But the following code does not work

index.php

```
//set status message
function setStatus($html){
    $("#data").html($html);
    }

//twitter login page handler
function twitter(){
    win = window.open('twit.php','win',"width=882,height=750,toolbar=0");
    setStatus('proccess...');
    }

//close window
 function closeWin(){
    win.close();
    }

//open new window
$(".twitterBtn").click(twitter);
```

twit.php

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.opener.setStatus('Login with Twitter!');
window.opener.closeWin();
</script>
```

My problem with window.opener, It does not work

Please suggest a way that will work in all browsers and does not conflict with other codes

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it took a while but I have a working example.

I use postMessage for the information exchange, however, it is only needed for letting the child know its parent.. but I extended the example to a parent-child chat. Have fun:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load",init,false);
        window.addEventListener("message",message,false); //register postMessages

        //we need this because master(original) and slave(=window.open) must do different actions
        var isSlave=window.location.href.indexOf("slave=true")>0

        //the other-window (in the slave, this is undefined, until the handshake is complete
        var popupwindow;
        if (!isSlave){
            popupwindow=window.open(window.location.href+"?slave=true", "_blank",'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0'); 
        }

        // this is called from the child window, after handshake
        function test(){
            var listElem = document.createElement('li');
            listElem.innerHTML="handshake succesful!!!!!";
            document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(listElem);
        }

        function init(){
            document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
                        ////popupwindow.test(); //note this works only if same origin policy allows this, else use postMessages

                //here we send the message to the other window
                popupwindow.postMessage(document.querySelector("#inp").value,"*");
            },false);


            //the timetrigger is needed, because opening and initializing the new window takes time, then we perform a handshake to let the new window know his origin
            setTimeout(function(){
            if(!isSlave)
                popupwindow.postMessage("handshake successful","*");//handsake needed for bidirectional conneciton  
            },200);


        }


        //called when receiving a message
        function message(data){

            //needed for bidirectional message
            if (!popupwindow){
                popupwindow=data.source;
                //popupwindow.postMessage("handshake successful","*"); //send the handshake back to the origin (notification purpose only) //instead, we do test()
                popupwindow.test();
            }

            //display the message
            var listElem = document.createElement('li');
            listElem.innerHTML=data.data;
            document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(listElem);


        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>say hello</button>
    <input type="text" id="inp" />
    <ul></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @clph3r Please explain how this method can present information from a child window to the parent window move
How do you address different pages?

Comment: like discussion service when you want login and send comment with twitter account

Comment: @alismith this code implements a chat between the parent and the child window. Just try it out..
Therefore you can send any information between these two windows.

Comment: you can send a postMessage from the child to the parent. A postMessage can contain any data, for example a json object. In my example, you just have to type some text in the inputfiled and click the button, then it sends this message to the parent.

It actially can adress multiple pages. just reload the page, then you will see two child-windows.. each of them can send data back to the client (have you tried it out, do you understand it?)

Comment: @clph3r this is awesome, but how can we handle if the child window is refreshed( I have a scenario where it requires me to navigate to a different URL). What I observed is it loses the popupwindow

Comment: @cIph3r is it possible to expand this example a little bit to pass focus between parent and child? Very cool what you did here :)